# Showing the "squashed diff" of multiple commits

Tags: git, git-diff, squash

I'm looking for a shell script which displays the total/squashed diff of selected commits (`$SELECTED_COMMITS`) belonging to the same branch.

**Background:** My team is working on a rather long-living feature branch containing hundreds of commits related to dozens of tickets, in no specific order. Each commit message is prefixed by the respective ticket number (`PROJECT-XXXXX`). Now I would like to review the changes introduced by all the commits belonging to a specific ticket and, to this end, look at the total/squashed diff of all these `$SELECTED_COMMITS`. I do *not* want this diff to contain any changes introduced by unrelated commits in between the ones I'm interested in.

**Requirements:** Needless to say, unrelated commits in between the `$SELECTED_COMMITS` might potentially have changed the same files as `$SELECTED_COMMITS` and therefore cause conflicts when being "omitted" from history – in this case the command should simply fail (`exit 1`) and print an appropiate error messages.

Ideally, the shell script should be a single shell command accepting a list of commit hashes, so that I could set it as git alias. Also, the shell script should neither modify the working tree nor the git repository. That is, all files on disk (whether in `.git` or the working tree) should be treated as read-only.

**The following commands do what I want**, except that they modify the working directory and they also leave the repo in an undesirable state in case of conflicts:

```
git checkout <parent of first relevant commit>
git cherry-pick -n <all relevant commits>
git diff
git checkout <original branch>  # Reset once I'm done looking at the diff
```

Another way of achieving what I want (short of not modifying the git repo and handling conflicts) would be to create a temporary copy of the branch in question, do an interactive rebase where I move all commits I'm interested in in such a way that they are direct successors of one another and then, afterwards, run `git diff <parent of first relevant commit> <last relevant commit>` (and, finally, `git checkout <original branch> && git branch -d <temporary branch>` to reset everything).

Can anyone think of a way to achieve what I want? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Woudln't you rather have one separate branch per feature (e.g : one for each `PROJECT-XXX` list of commits) ? The script you describe already does that work.

Comment: @LeGEC No, in our specific case we don't (for various reasons).

Answer (score 0):

If your only issue is to avoid breaking your index or worktree :

[`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) will allow you to have a fresh index and worktree, separate from the main one :

```
# will create a worktree at '/tmp/checkXXX', on your current commit,
# in 'detached HEAD' state, and a separate index file
git worktree add /tmp/checkXXX HEAD
```

Changing files or creating merge conflicts from within `/tmp/checkXXX` will not alter your initial clone.

---

Once you are done with that particular worktree, you can remove it :

```
git worktree remove /tmp/checkXXX
```

To list existing worktrees, run :

```
git worktree list
```